# Character for inserting line break instead of creating paragraph in Android

Tags: android, text, textview, line-breaks

Is there a character for inserting `line break` without creating new `paragraph` in `TextView`?

Really I have a bidirectional text and want to display it in `TextView`. Now I have to add line breaks between `LTR` and `RTL` parts of text without changing direction of text after each line break.

It is obvious that using `\n` creates new paragraphs so direction of each new paragraph will be determined by its content and will be not typeset with direction of whole of the text.

In `LibreOffice Writer` we can use <kbd>SHIFT+ENTER</kbd> for adding line breaks instead of new paragraphs. Is this possible in `Android`? Note I do not want to use `<br/>` tag of `HTML`.

Comment: Have you tried to set the layout direction of the TextView with android:layoutDirection="ltr" ?

Answer (score 0):

you can use **\n** where you want to break the line as below

```
textView.setText("Hello \n World")
```

or

```
<TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Hello \n World"
                android:textSize="45dp"/>
```

Comment: I mentioned that "\n" creates new paragraph.